# How to dismiss cell and make the recyclerview assumes the position of the dismissed item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to achieve the design when i click on the x(circled cross) it dismisses and  the recyclerview assumes the position:

[image: i am trying to achieve the design when i click on the x(circled cross) it dismisses and the recyclerview assumes the position]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OnItemClick:-

**notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,count);**  //IF you are removing top item in your recycler view.